# Cassandra 3 trigger on delete operation

Tags: triggers, cassandra

I'm trying to implement a trigger on Cassandra 3 to catch delete operations on a specific table by implementing

```
 public Collection<Mutation> augment(Partition partition)
```

on `ITrigger` interface but I can't differentiate between update and delete operations.

How can I catch that the operation is a delete operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here is how you can catch all type of deletion**

```
public Collection<Mutation> augment(Partition partition) {
    if(partition.partitionLevelDeletion().isLive()) {
        UnfilteredRowIterator it = partition.unfilteredIterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Unfiltered unfiltered = it.next();
            switch (unfiltered.kind()) {
                case ROW:
                    Row row = (Row) unfiltered;
                    
                    if (!row.deletion().isLive()) {
                        // Row deletion
                    }

                    for (Cell cell : row.cells()) {
                        if (cell.isTombstone()) {
                            // Cell deletion
                        } else {
                            // Insert or Update
                        }  
                    }
                    break;
                case RANGE_TOMBSTONE_MARKER:
                    // Range Deletion
                    break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Partition Level Deletion
    }
}
```

Let's say we have the table :

```
CREATE TABLE kv (
    pk int,
    ck int,
    d int,
    PRIMARY KEY (pk, ck)
);
```

**Here pk is the partition key and ck is the clustering key**

Partition Level Deletion :

```
DELETE from kv WHERE pk = 1;
```

Range Deletion :

```
DELETE from kv WHERE pk = 1 AND ck > 10;
```

Row deletion :

```
 DELETE from kv WHERE pk = 1 AND ck = 10;
```

And cell deletion :

```
DELETE d from kv WHERE pk = 1 AND ck = 10;
```

Comment: Thanks Ashraful. Which one will called when I run the command "delete from my_table where id=22"

Comment: Is id is the partition key ? If yes then it will be a partition Level deletion

Comment: You mean that the else "else {
        // Partition Level Deletion
    }" will be called on this case? And will the "else" called on update operation also?

Comment: Only if it is delete the code `else { // Partition Level Deletion }` will call

Comment: For Insert or Update or Range or Delete(When you specify clustering key or null insert) operation first if will call

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. The "if(partition.partitionLevelDeletion().isLive()){}" called with insert and update only and the "else" with delete only. That's right?

Comment: Thanks @Ashraful. So, the whole if and else called on delete operation only. But, when the insert and update called?

Comment: @M.Almokadem Answer Updated

Comment: I've test the and it's working with Partition level deletion but there are some changes while (partition.hasNext()) ==> UnfilteredRowIterator it = partition.unfilteredIterator(); while(it.hasNext())

Unfiltered unfiltered = partition.next(); ==> Unfiltered unfiltered = it.next();

Comment: @M.Almokadem Could you please illustrate how did you use it? Like I'm getting the resultset from cassandra but how to use it for this method? And I'm getting errors like there is no method deletion() and cell(). Could you please help?

Comment: @AshrafulIslam Could you please explain with exact code snippet? I'm not able to understand on how to use it. I'm not able to find any documentation on using triggers.

Comment: @AshrafulIslam How do I get a partition update from cluster to send to the mutation method?

Comment: @AshrafulIslam I added the audit trigger jar to cassandra. Now a table is being created. In a java file I'm trying to fetch the deleted rows using the trigger. I am overriding the augment method of ITrigger. Now, I'm fetching all the rows from database and sending the ID's to augment method to check if it is deleted using the above suggest. Is this how is it done? I'm not able to parse row to partition Update. Could you please help?

Comment: @bhargavaravalikoganti You are misunderstanding the trigger concept. If you create a trigger on a table and you delete, update or insert a record on that table the trigger's augment method will called with the record