# Cassandra triggers only for deletes

Tags: triggers, cassandra, delete-row

Basically, triggers are not possible in cassandra. Using a [custom](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/examples/triggers/src/org/apache/cassandra/triggers/AuditTrigger.java) trigger jar, triggers can be formed. However, like in sql is it possible to have trigger only for deletes in cassandra?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45532725/2320144

Comment: Thanks for the link. So, is it like if I build a jar file with this code, will it keep track of only deletes of my table?

Comment: There are some block in the code that will be called when you execute delete operation

Comment: Well, I require only the deletes to be handled. I do not want updates and also inserts to be added to the family. This is because, I have around 10gb of data where I cannot iterate through and find out which is a delete operation. Is there any code available only for delete operations.

Comment: No there is no such way

Comment: triggers in C* are not like they are in sql, its a very advanced specialized feature that isnt recommended to solve normal problems. If your looking for auditing I would recommend looking into CDC instead.

Comment: @ChrisLohfink How does cdc work? For suppose there I created a table with cdc=true and there are 10 rows in it. If I delete a row in it will I be able to capture the deleted id? Like this for two simultaneous row deletes.

Comment: it will record every mutation occurring on that replica, including the deletes

Comment: SO, how can I access the deletes using CDC using java API?